# Using ruby-debug in for i in 0...5

Tags: ruby, debugging

I am learning ruby from 'Programming ruby 1.9'. I am learning to use the ruby-debug so I can understand what is going on underneath. I use rubymine since it integrates ruby-debug19 or something like that (it says I don't have the gem and installs it). Here is the question, I was able to step through the code and explore the variables and the stack. However, when it reaches a `for i in 0...5`, the debugger says

> stack frame not available

I know that ruby don't use for loops much but I'd still like to know if there debug through for loops.

Code:

```
    raw_text  = %{
The problem breaks down into two parts. First, given some text as a
string, return a list of words. That sounds like an array. Then, build a 
count for each distinct word. That sounds like a use for a hash---we can 
index it with the word and use the corresponding entry to keep a count.}

word_list = words_from_string(raw_text)
counts    = count_frequency(word_list)
sorted    = counts.sort_by {|word, count| count}
top_five  = sorted.last(5)

for i in 0...5            # (this is ugly code--read on
  word = top_five[i][0]   #  for a better version)
  count = top_five[i][1]
  puts "#{word}:  #{count}"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the Ruby Language Specification (clause 11.5.2.3.4 on p. 91), you will see that

```
for i in 0...5
  word = top_five[i][0]
  count = top_five[i][1]
  puts "#{word}:  #{count}"
end
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
(0...5).each do |i|
  word = top_five[i][0]
  count = top_five[i][1]
  puts "#{word}:  #{count}"
end
```

*except* that *no new variable scope* is created for the block. So, the code with `for` will be translated into the code with `each` and executed as if it were written that way, except that the variables used in the `for` loop leak into the surrounding scope.

To put it another way: `for` actually executes `each` but *without allocating a new stack frame for the block*. So, the error message is exactly right: there is a call to a block, but somehow there is no stack frame allocated for that block call. That obviously confuses the debugger.

Now, one might argue that this is a bug and that `for` loops should get special treatment inside the debugger. I guess that so far nobody has ever bothered to fix that bug, since nobody ever uses `for` loops, precisely because they leak their variables into the surrounding scope and are *exactly* equivalent to an idiomatic `each` which doesn't.

What do I mean by "leaking variables"? See here:

```
(1..2).each do |i|
  t = true
end

i
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `i' for main:Object

t
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `t' for main:Object

for i in 1..2
  t = true
end

i
# => 2

t
# => true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was actually hoping to know how to debug and know the values in the variables such that (1..2).each do |i| and i would be able to debug through and see the value i or other vars changing while using the debugger. What you explained was indeed fascinating and educational. THanks :)